# How to broadcast intent to android application?

Tags: android, shell, android-studio, android-broadcast

To test my Google Analytics setup , i need to broadcast INSTALL_REFERRER Intent manually.

Here is what i did (I am using mac):

1. `cd android-sdks/platform-tools/`
2. run this :

   `shell am broadcast -a com.android.vending.INSTALL_REFERRER 
    -n"com.example.gatestapp/com.google.android.gms.analytics.CampaignTrackingReceiver" --es referre "utm_source=testSource&utm_medium=testMedium&utm_term=testTerm&utm_content  =testContent&utm_campaign=testCampaign"`

But i got this error : `-bash: shell: command not found`.

What should i do ?

Comment: Have you tried like `./adb shell am broadcast -a ....` ?

Comment: @ρяσѕρєя thank you for your answer , one minute i will try

Comment: Shell is a parameter to the adb program, you have to call it like `./adb shell ...`

Comment: thank you very much, yes i should set ./adb.